# How to make Python 2.7 and Python 3.1 coexist on windows 7?

Tags: python

I have a Python 3.1 installed on my desktop but now I need to have Python 2.7 to run CQL. I installed both versions Python on my box, type 'Python', the 3.1 version was invoked. but when I tried to use 2.7 version by specified the path of the executable of 2.7, the 3.1 was invoked again, with some errors, as listed below:

```
C:\Python27>.\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site.py", line 56, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python31\lib\os.py", line 380, in <module>
    from _abcoll import MutableMapping  # Can't use collections (bootstrap)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\_abcoll.py", line 54
    class Hashable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what should/could I do to make both Python version work for me?

Comment: What happens if you invoke python like this: `C:\Python27>.\python.exe -E`

Comment: What are the results of `echo %PYTHONPATH%` and `echo %PYTHONHOME%`?

Answer (score 3):

Either use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to have a nice bash environment that makes it easy to launch python scripts with specific interpreters, or, use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create environments based on specific interps:

```
> mkdir project
> cd project
> C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe -p C:\Python32\python.exe .
> Scripts\activate
```

At this point, your env has been set to this project, and typing `python` will start python3.2
You would type `deactivate` to revert back to normal env. With this approach, you can either set this up on a per project basis to manage version dependencies between python projects, or you can make this more global for each python version in general. Up to you.

In *nix based systems we  have the luxury of the "shebang" line at the top of the script to tell it which interpreter to use. Windows only has file extension associations via the GUI, and you have to be explicit in the command line in form of `python <script.py>`